# Why $Q_n$ in the proof of Stone-Weierstrass theorem( Baby Rudin ) converges uniformly to zero?

Tags: real-analysis

I am reading Rudin's Principles of mathematical analysis, Third Edition, p.159, 7.26 Theorem ( The Stone-Weierstrass Theorem ) and some question arises.

> **7.26 Theorem** : If $f$ is a continuous complex function on $[a,b]$, there exists a sequence of polynomials $P_n$ such that $$ \lim_{n\to \infty}P_n(x) = f(x)$$ uniformly on $[a,b]$. If $f$ is real, the $P_n$ may be taken real.

In the proof, he set for each positive integer $n$

$$ Q_n(x) : = c_n (1-x^2)^n$$

where $c_n$ is chosen so that $$ \int_{-1}^{1} Q_n(x)dx=1.$$

Then through some estimates, he deduce that

$$ c_n < \sqrt{n}$$

Then for $0 < \delta <1$, he deduce that

$$ Q_n(x) \leq \sqrt{n}(1-\delta^2)^n$$

for all $x$, $\delta \leq  |x| \leq 1$

And he claims that $Q_n(x) \to 0$ uniformly in $\delta \le |x| \le 1$. Why this is true?

Is information for understanding this question provided sufficiently? If needed, I will upload further detailed proof.

C.f. In manfred stoll's 'Introduction to Real Analysis, Second Edition', in page.351, along with similar proof, he offers that noting $ 0 < (1-\delta^2) <1$ , we may use the Theorem 2.2.6 (d), which is stated as follows :

> **2.2.6 Theorem -(d)** : If $p>1$ and $\alpha$ is real, then $\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{n^{\alpha}}{p^n}=0$.

Can we really use this theorem? How?

Can anyone helps?

Comment: Because $\sup_{x\in [-\delta ,1]}|Q_n(x)|\leq\sqrt n(1-\delta ^2)^n\to 0$ when $n\to \infty $.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Take  $p=\frac 1 {1-\delta^{2}}$ in Theorem 2.2.6.

Comment: O.K. I also cognize such application on my own. I think that I propose soft question too hastily. Anyway thanks.